# Comparing pointers

Tags: c, ascii

This code is to convert integer numbers to character numbers. I can not understand why the **condition** of this while loop: *while(savestr < str)* will be true until the end of that loop?!

```
 while (savestr < str) {
          temp = *str ;
          *str-- = *savestr ;
          *savestr++ = temp ;
```

In what aspect that constion works? ASCII value? So in aspect of ASCII value how the loop condition works?!

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void int_to_ascii( int , char *);
int main()
{
    int number ;
    char s[10] ;
    clrscr();
    printf(" enter a number :");
    scanf("%d", &number) ;
    int_to_ascii(number, s) ;
    printf(" the string value is: %s ", s);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
//**********************************
void int_to_ascii(int value, char *str)
{
    int saveval = value ;
    char temp, *savestr = str ;
    if(value < 0)
    value *= -1 ;
    do{
    *str++ = (value % 10) + 48 ;
    value = value / 10 ;
    } while(value > 0);
    if (saveval < 0)
       *str++ = '-' ;
    *str-- = '\0' ;
    while(savestr < str) {
      temp = *str ;
      *str-- = *savestr ;
      *savestr++ = temp ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Spaces between unary operators and operands are making the code less readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop:

```
    do {
        *str++ = (value % 10) + 48;
        value = value / 10;
    } while (value > 0);
```

Converts `value` to a numeral by taking the last digit (`value % 10`), adding the ASCII code for the character “0” (48), and putting the sum in `str` (`*str =`). It also increments `str` to point to the next space in memory (`*str++ =`). Adding the code for “0” works because, in C, the codes for the digit characters “0” through “9” are consecutive (in ASCII: 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57). So, if the last digit of value (`value % 10`) is 5, adding 5 to 48 produces 53, which is the code for “5”.

There is no reason to use `48` here. The code would be better written as `*str++ = (value % 10) + '0';`. This has two benefits: It makes it clear to a reader that we are adding the code for the character “0”; they do not need to remember or figure out what 48 is. And it removes the assumption that ASCII is in use; this code will work with other character code schemes.

Then `value = value / 10;` removes the last digit, leaving the earlier digits of `value`, if any. And `while (value > 0)` continues the loop if there are any more digits.

When this loop is done, the memory that `str` initially pointed to contains the characters of the numeral for `value`. However, they are backwards, because we wrote the last digit first and the first digit last. And `str` now points to the end of the characters (one position beyond the last one). The saved value in `savestr` points to the first position.

This code:

```
    if (saveval < 0)
        *str++ = '-';
    *str-- = '\0';
```

adds a minus sign if the value is negative and then adds a null character to mark the end of the string. It leaves `str` pointing to the last position before the null character.

Since the digits were written in reverse order, we must reverse them. This loop does that:

```
    while (savestr < str) {
        temp = *str;
        *str-- = *savestr;
        *savestr++ = temp;
    }
```

`savestr < str` is true as long as `savestr` points to an earlier place in the allocated memory than `str` does. When two pointers are compared, if they point to elements in the same array, one is less than the other if it points to an earlier element (one with a lower array index). Initially, `savestr` points to the first character in the string, and `str` points to the last character (before the terminating null character).

Then:

- `temp = *str;` remembers the character that `str` points to.
- `*str-- = *savestr;` moves the character that `savestr` points to to the place that `str` points to, and, because of the `--`, it decrements `str` to point to earlier in memory.
- `*savestr++ = temp;` puts the remembered character in the place `savestr` points to, and, because of the `++`, it increments `savestr` to point to later in memory.

Thus characters from earlier in the string are swapped with characters later in the string, and `savestr` is advanced to later in the string while `str` is moved to earlier in the string. Eventually, `savestr` and `str` meet or cross, and the `while` condition `savestr < str` becomes false, at which point the loop stops, and the string has been reversed.

Comment: thanks a lot. but one other thing is that, According to [C book information](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators_precedence.htm) the priority of `++` is higher than `==` .So what is the reason that for example in this code :  `*str++ = '-'` , at first it is checking for the negative sign symbol, and then skipping over it while in according to C book must at first skipping over and then checking for that symbol?

Comment: @MohammadRazmjoo: (a) The precedence of operators affects how expressions are structured, not the order in which their parts are evaluated. (b) The definition of postfix `++`, that is, a `++` that appears after its operand, is that its **value** is the value of the operand before the operation and its **side effect** on the operand is to increment it. Thus, even if `++` is evaluated first, the side effect occurs off to the side; it does not affect the value produced in the expression.

Comment: With thanks for your attention, may I ask a question that for what reason should I use `*str-- = *savestr;` ? As I know it replace digits in `*str` with space memories in `*savestr`, is it true? why to do this? Because of the loop condition `savestr < str` to be true? Is it generally an empty string array smaller than a string with value? I think `*str-- = *savestr;` is necessary for the time `savestr` and `str` meet together, am I right?

Comment: @MohammadRazmjoo: You should step through the code, both figuring out manually what it does and with a debugger. If you do not have a debugger you can use yet, insert `printf` statements to figure out what each part of the program is doing. Watch the values of the variables and the things they point to as the loop goes through each iteration.